# logical(0) in if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, na

This line:

```
which(!is.na(c(NA,NA,NA))) == 0
```

produces `logical(0)`

While this line

```
if(which(!is.na(c(NA,NA,NA))) == 0){print('TRUE')}
```

generates:

```
Error in if (which(!is.na(c(NA, NA, NA))) == 0) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Why there is an error? What is logical(0)

Comment: A logical (i.e. boolean) vector of length 0. Since it has zero length, it doesn't have a truth value, so the `if` clause fails.

Comment: You can do something like that: `if(any(!is.na(c(NA,NA,NA))) == 0){print('TRUE')}`

Comment: If you replace `which` with `sum` you will get the expected behavior, i.e. `if(sum(!is.na(c(NA,NA,NA))) == 0){print('TRUE')}`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`logical(0)` is a vector of base type logical with 0 length. You're getting this because your asking which elements of this vector equal 0:

```
> !is.na(c(NA, NA, NA))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
> which(!is.na(c(NA, NA, NA))) == 0
logical(0)
```

In the next line, you're asking if that zero length vector `logical(0)` is equal to 0, which it isn't. You're getting an error because you can't compare a vector of 0 length with a scalar.

Instead you could check whether the length of that first vector is 0:

```
if(length(which(!is.na(c(NA,NA,NA)))) == 0){print('TRUE')}
```

Comment: "vector of class logical" should be "vector of mode logical" I think.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer why do you think it should be mode instead of class?

Comment: Because "class" is the term for the object-oriented universes, but "mode" is (actually the old) R terminology for "base type". "base type" is better.  From: [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/base-types.html): _Technically, the difference between base and OO objects is that OO objects have a “class” attribute_ butt also: _You may have heard of mode() and storage.mode(). Do not use these functions: they exist only to provide type names that are compatible with S._

Comment: OK thanks for the suggestion. I've changed "class" to "base type" as it seems the best choice of the three.

Answer (score 8):

Calling `which` to check whether a vector of logicals is all false is a bad idea. `which` gives you a vector of indices for TRUE values. If there are none, that vector is length-0. A better idea is to make use of `any`.

```
> any(!is.na(c(NA,NA,NA)))
FALSE
```

Answer (score 7):

First off, `logical(0)` indicates that you have a vector that's supposed to contain boolean values, but the vector has zero length.

In your first approach, you do

```
!is.na(c(NA, NA, NA))
# FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
```

Using the `which()` on this vector, will produce an empty integer vector (`integer(0)`). Testing whether an empty set is equal to zero, will thus lead to an empty boolean vector.

In your second approach, you try to see whether the vector `which(!is.na(c(NA,NA,NA))) == 0` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. However, it is neither, because it is empty. The `if`-statement needs either a `TRUE` or a `FALSE`.  That's why it gives you an error `argument is of length zero`

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `length()` like so:

```
foo <- logical(0)

if(length(foo) == 0) { } # TRUE
if(length(foo) != 0) { } # FALSE
```