# What does factor(0) mean?

Tags: r

I'm doing research in immunology and want to determine the names of genes that meet certain requirements.

```
ifng5p <- df$Gene[which(as.numeric(df$Prop1) <= df[df$Genes == "Ifng", "Prop1.5p"] 
& as.numeric(df$Prop1) >= df[df$Genes== "Ifng", "Prop1.5m"] & as.numeric(df$Prop1) <= df[df$Genes == "Ifng", "Prop1.5p"] 
& as.numeric(df$Prop1) >= df[df$Genes=="Ifng", "Prop1.5m"])]
```

I'm expecting the names of genes (which are in the column 'Gene') to be outputted and instead my output is the following:

```
factor(0)
49041 Levels:  0610005C13Rik 0610006L08Rik 0610009B22Rik 0610009E02Rik 0610009L18Rik ... Zzz3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [logical(0) in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626193/logical0-in-if-statement)

Comment: Please include `dput(head(df))` in your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`factor(0)` means a vector of type `factor` with a length of  0. You're getting that because your subsetting isn't returning any values. You can see an example of this with the `iris` dataset:

```
# There are no cats in `iris` so it returns a vector of length 0
iris$Species[iris$Species ==  'cat']

factor(0)
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

This is because `iris$Species ==  'cat'` is `FALSE` for all values and so no values are returned. The `table` function nicely counts up each value in a vector and we can use it to see that `iris$Species == 'cat'` gives us 150 `FALSE` values and 0 `TRUE`:

```
table(iris$Species == 'cat')

FALSE 
  150
```

Comment: Nice and clear answer. The great thing about R is that you can check the intermediary parts of your code easily. If the results of the selection were checked like `iris$Species ==  'cat'` , it would be clear everything was `FALSE` and no rows were selected. `table(iris$Species ==  'cat')` could also be used as a nicer way to check the number of rows picked out too.